# Remove _class from Spring MongoDB in Kotlin

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin

While using Kotlin with Spring to manage a MongoDB collection, every new document comes with _class field. I'm not sure how that is getting inserted. What is the best way to prevent this from happening. My Kotlin data class looks like this

```
data class Student(
    @Id
    val _id: String? = null,
    val name: String,
    val grade: String,
    val status: String,
    val format: String
)
```